# Fine Uploader - the noFilesError don't show

Tags: fine-uploader

```
 var manualuploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        element: $('#manual-fine-uploader')[0],
        request: {
            endpoint: '/ViewData/UploadFile'
        },
        autoUpload: false,
        multiple: false,
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ['xlsx']
        },
        text: {
            uploadButton: 'select file',
            cancelButton: 'cancel file'
        },
        messages: {
            typeError: '{file} file type error : {extensions}.',
            noFilesError: "no files ."
        },
        failedUploadTextDisplay: {
            mode: 'custom',
            maxChars: 40,
            responseProperty: 'Msg',
            enableTooltip: true
        },
        callbacks: {
            onUpload: function (id, name) {
                showWaitLayer("uploading ......");
            },
            onComplete: function (id, name, response) {
                closeWaitLayer();
                $('input[name=uploadFileName]').val(response.Datas.FILE_0);
            }
        }
    });
```

I use this code , when i select a 'jpg' file,the typeError will alter; 
my question is when the noFilesError will show? i try lots time the noFileError didn't show.

Comment: Are you having a specific problem, or are you just wondering about the specific circumstances the noFilesError might be displayed?

Comment: i want displayed the noFilesError but i can't,how can i display the noFilesError(my english not good,sorry),thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on [options](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/options/fineuploaderbasic.html) clearly states:

> `noFilesError` - Text sent to the `onError` callback (and `showMessage` if running in FineUploader mode) if a an empty array of files or `Blob` objects is submitted.

And on [callbacks](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/callbacks.html):

> `onError(String id, String name, String errorReason, XMLHttpRequest xhr)` - called whenever an exceptional condition occurs (during an upload, file selection, etc). Note that the last parameter, xhr, will only be included if the error is related to a request initiated by XMLHttpRequest.

If you simply want an error to display when no files have been droppped onto the uploader, add an anonymous function to your `onError` callback like so:

```js
// ...
callbacks: {
    onError: function (id, name, errorReason, xhr) {
        alert(errorReason);
    }
}
// ...
```

This will display a simple alert whenever there is an error. You could customize when and how you display your error by manipulating the logic inside of the `onError` callback.

Comment: i add onError yesterday, i use a button to call 'manualuploader.uploadStoredFiles();' when i click the button to upload file , the noFilesError not trigger. my Version is 3.5.0

Comment: and when i add this onError Alert, the typeError will alert two times

Answer (score 0):

finally,i update to 3.64 version,and before uploadStoredFiles() method i add

```
  var tempA = manualuploader.getUploads({
                    status: [qq.status.SUBMITTED]
                });
  if (tempA.length == 0){
      alert("no File Error");
      return;
  }
```

Comment: What version were you using? The latest version is 3.7.0 -- so many bug fixes, features added, algorithms optimized, and browser incompatibilities fixed since then.

Comment: At begin i used 3.5.0,after i used 3.64